# Text Index Weights and Other Options not Applied with Language

Tags: mongodb, indexing

So I'm trying in my local environment (Mongo in my own PC) to index some items for spanish, using weights like so:

```
db.news.createIndex({
      title: "text",
      description: "text"
    }, {
      default_language: "spanish"
    }, {
      weights: {
        title: 10,
        description: 5
      },
      name: "SpanishIndex"
    });
```

Now the issue is that it does not seem to work, here are my Robo3t screen of the index:

**Name and Keys do not match**

[image: Name and Keys do not match]

**Weights do not match**

[image: Weights do not match]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually specified the "options" incorrectly as **three** separate objects when it should have been **one**.

> [Usage From Documentation:](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) db.collection.createIndex(**keys**, **options**)

So you should drop the create index and re-create correctly:

```
db.news.dropIndexes();
db.news.createIndex(
  { title: "text", description: "text" },
  { 
    default_language: "spanish",
    weights: { title: 10, description: 5 },
    name: "SpanishIndex"
  }
)
```

Which will then show the options correctly applied:

```
  {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_fts" : "text",
            "_ftsx" : 1
        },
        "name" : "SpanishIndex",
        "ns" : "test.news",
        "default_language" : "spanish",
        "weights" : {
            "description" : 5,
            "title" : 10
        },
        "language_override" : "language",
        "textIndexVersion" : 3
    }
```